# Compare ID based on Year and collect the missing IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to compare table 1 with table 2 based on date and collec the data based on their year of generation. The problem here is, i want to also capture the non-matching ids from table 1 and their difference with table-2.

table_1

| id | finace_num | date_old | data_IDENTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 880 | 2020 | 5699 |
| H | 4580 | 2019 | 5694 |
| X1 | 5903 | 2003 | 9Rt56 |
| Y | 5555 | 2020 | 99333 |
| J1 | 9999 | 2020 | 33333 |

table_2

| id | address | date_new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | US | 2019 |
| A | US | 2020 |
| Y1 | UK | 2020 |
| Y2 | - | 2020 |
| A3 | NA | 2019 |
| X1 | - | 2003 |
| X1 | - | 2003 |

Output

| Year | Id count in table 1 | Id count in table 2 | table 1 id that is missing in table 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 2019 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2003 | 1 | 2 | 0 |

- Here there are 3 recs for year 2020 and in table_1 and table_2. Since only one record is matching (id: A) in both table 1 and table 2, i take the count of the missing ids and add it to the last field.
- In Second record, there is 1 rec for 2019 in table_1 and 2 in table_2. Since the ids in table1 doesn't match with the id in table 2,i take the count of the missing id i.e. 2 and add it to the last field.

What i tried so far is

```
select table_1.date_old, 
count(table_1.id) over ( partition by table_1.date_old ) as [Id count in table 1],
count(table_2.id) over ( partition by table_1.date_old ) as [Id count in table 2]
from
table_1, table_2
```

Comment: since my attempts didn't even get closer to the result, i restrained away from posting. I've edited the topic to include what i've tried now.

Comment: Its always helpful to see how you approached the problem, not only does it clarify the problem, but it clarifies what help you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT Year = COALESCE (t1.date_old, t2.date_new)
, "Id count in table 1" = COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id) 
, "Id count in table 2" =COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id) 
, "table 1 id that is missing in table 2" = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN t2.id IS NULL THEN t1.id ELSE NULL END ) 
FROM table_1  t1
  FULL OUTER JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t1.date_old = t2.date_new
    AND t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY COALESCE (t1.date_old, t2.date_new)
```

Comment: what is the purpose of **ON t1.date_old = t2.date_new**? the output should have dates only from table 1, we can't match the same from table 2.

Comment: It is the condition when you join the two table. I recommend you should read more on the SQL stuff. Sincerely, :)

Comment: you got me wrong. my point was why are we joining based on dates.

Comment: Why not? We have a problem, we would do whatever method we have on our hand to solve it.